# ERROR: Installing pip is forbidden, this will break the python-pip package (termux)?

Tags: python, pip, updates, termux, termux-linux

Already tried  `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `pkg install python-pip` but nothing helps ):

someone told me to use python virtual environments, and then maybe I can update pip inside the virtual environment

should I try this?

Comment: I do not know about termux specifically, but definitely it is not a good idea to try to update the global *pip* and it is much better to use Python virtual environments as soon as pip is involved one way or another.